# GDB command clarification

Tags: assembly, gdb, disassembly

What does this code do?

```
0x804a408(%edx)
```

What does this command do?

Here is some GDB output

```
(gdb) x/d 0x804a408
0x804a408 <array.3144>: 109
(gdb) x/s 0x804a408
0x804a408 <array.3144>: "maduiersnfotvbylWow! You've defused the secret stage!"
(gdb) x/x 0x804a408
0x804a408 <array.3144>: 0x6d
```

Comment: That's a memory reference for `0x804a408+edx`. Switch to intel syntax if you don't know at&t. You haven't shown the instruction so we don't know what it does. Did you look at the question I linked you in my other comment?

Comment: Did not see the link! Thank you!